# To Do List Item's are not able to be Edited in Datasheet Mode on the Task List

Tags: task-list

I have several workflows connected to the Task list. When a user tries to edit their to-do items on the Task list, they have to edit each task as Complete one by one from the normal view. I want people to be able to change multiple tasks as Complete in the Datasheet view for ease.

This ONLY happens for To-Do items. The other list items edit fine in Datasheet view. The error I get is totally non specific and the changes just won't take.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you get it when changing any of the columns?